# page content container won't fully stretch vertically when zoomed in

Tags: html, css, stretch

I'm trying to create a centered, page container that will vertically stretch across the page when the page is zoomed in or zoomed out. The page container stretches perfectly when zoomed out, but when I zoom in, I can see a space between the bottom of the page container and the browser window. I'm using Chrome to test my CSS.

Here is the HTML and CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
body{
text-align: center;  
padding:0px; 
margin:0px; 
height:100%;
}
#page{
margin: 0 auto;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
width:980px;
height:100%;
}
#content{
border:0px solid black;
width:980;
height:800; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
    <div id="content">
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not good (no units, plus fixed height):

```
#content{
border:0px solid black;
width:980;
height:800; 
}
```

One fix is to change it to:

```
#content{
border:0px solid black;
width:980px;
}
```

Optionally also use `height: 100%;`, but subtract any margin, padding, and border -- as necessary.

Comment: `border: 0px solid black;` is the same as `border: 0;` (no unit required on zero-values)

Comment: @feeela, I know, but that was straight out of the OP's code -- probably for debug purposes or future plans.

Comment: setting height to 100% worked, but I have another problem. If I put in any content that's too tall into the "#content" div, it will go out of the "#page" div. For example, if a paragraph is too long, it will flow out of the container. Please help!

Comment: For that you would add `overflow-y: auto;` to the `#page` style.